Hardhat test Error. "TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function"
I am using Hardhat to unit test a Solidity smart contract in Sepolia Network.When I try to test my contract, I get this error: "TypeError: (0 , ethers_1.getAddress) is not a function". I think there is dependency conflict between diferent versions of ethers, hardhat and maybe @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox. I have tried to change the dependency versions but the Error persists.
In this case I am trying to test that owner is set correctly at contract deployment. It is basically testing the following line in the Faucet.sol constructor:
"owner = payable(msg.sender)".
I want to test it with my Sepolia account, so I used "ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider" to get my account. This was possible with "ethers": "^5.7.2".
Faucet.sol:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract Faucet {
  address payable public owner;

  constructor() payable {
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
  }
  
  function withdraw(uint _amount) payable public {
    // users can only withdraw .1 ETH at a time, feel free to change this!
    require(_amount <= 100000000000000000);
    (bool sent, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: _amount}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
  }

  function withdrawAll() onlyOwner public {
    (bool sent, ) = owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
  }

  function destroyFaucet() onlyOwner public {
    selfdestruct(owner);
  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }
}

faucetTests.js
const { loadFixture } = require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");


describe('Faucet', function () {
  
  async function deployContractAndSetVariables() {
  
   const url = process.env.RPC_URL;
   let privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
   const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);
   let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
   console.log('Signer 1 address: ', wallet.address);
  
  const Faucet = await ethers.getContractFactory('Faucet');
  const faucet = await Faucet.deploy();
  await faucet.deployed();
  return { wallet, faucet };
  }

  it('should deploy and set the owner correctly', async function () {
    const { wallet, faucet } = await loadFixture(deployContractAndSetVariables);

    expect(await faucet.owner()).to.equal(wallet.address);
  });
});

hardhat.config.js
 require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require('dotenv').config()

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",

  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: process.env.RPC_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      sepolia: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
  },
};

package.json
{
  "name": "how-to-unit-test-a-smart-contract",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.4.2",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.22.16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "web3modal": "^1.9.12"
  }
}


You are trying to call the function getAddress on the object ethers_1. If this does not contain the function it is not initialized the way you expect it. So you could type check before calling any property on it.

This question is similar to: How to tell if a JavaScript function is defined. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
